# Matérn covariance in R is returning matrices that are not positive definite

Tags: r, gaussian-process, covariance-matrix

In R, I am trying to calculate a Matérn covariance matrix whose inputs are randomly created distance matrices. However, I end up getting covariance matrices that are not positive definite, which makes little sense.

First I generate a random distance matrix:

```
nrows <- 100
ncols <- 100
d <- matrix(runif(nrows*ncols, 0, 1), ncols, nrows)
# enforce symmetry:
d[lower.tri(d)] <- t(d)[lower.tri(d)]
diag(d) <- 0.000000000001 # instead of zero to avoid numerical issues
# check that we have a correct distance matrix:
range(d)
```

Then I follow this Wikipedia formula for Matérn covariances:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZGBg.png)

```
# Calculate Matérn covariance matrix:
sigma <- 1
v <- 3
p <- 5
term1 <- (2**(1-v))/(gamma(v))
term2 <- (sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p))**v
term3 <- besselK(sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p), nu = v)
m <- (sigma**2)*term1*term2*term3
```

However, when I check the eigenvalues of the Matérn covariance matrix, I see that it's not a positive definite matrix, as it should be:

```
g <- eigen(m, only.values=TRUE)
print(min(g$values)) # should be greter than zero
print(sum(g$values<0)/length(g$values)) # thus, this should be zero
```

I fail to understand what am I doing wrong and how to make sure I generate a positive definite Matérn covariance matrix when passing to it a distance matrix.

Comment: first your matrix should be a matrix of distances. Therefore the diagonal should be 0

Comment: @Onyambu oh yeah, I forgot to copy/pate that line of code. Edited now with it (obviously, the issue remains)

Comment: The problem probably arises in `term2`, you shouldn't use `**` here (which is element-wise exponentiation) and instead use matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Jan the formula is correct. Yes `**` is exponentiation which OP wants. Also you could try directly with the function `geoR::matern(d,3/2,1)` and the kernel produced is not positive definite. I so not know whether its the input matrix. Perhaps OP should try with a real distance matrix instead of a randomized one

Comment: @Jan hmmm, but shouldn't this be element-wise really? The equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function) is for scalar values, so when applied to a matrix in the R code, I think it is simply applying the whole thing element-wise in a vectorized fashion

Comment: @Onyambu I did try with a few real distance matrix and occasionally, the same happens. Also, I do need to be able to use randomized matrices for the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I did a quick google and it turns out matern function does face this issue of sometimes producing non-positive definite results. You need to change the parameters is nu and kappa. ensure nu(v) >=0.5 etc

Comment: @Onyambu that is interesting. Perhaps this may require a question to Cross-Validated, instead of here, since there seems to be something theoretically challenging at play. Also, I didn't get what you meant by ensuring $nu(v) >= 0.5$.

Comment: the v/nu/shape parameter should be a larger number.. not close to 0.. Just some information I got. You can google

Comment: Since the code appears to be working as expected, I have voted to migrate the question to Cross Validated.

Comment: @Axeman not necessary. I just posted a new version of the question there and will delete this one.